How to show the full legend label as a tooltip on hovering over the legend symbol in vega lite
I am working on a use case where I want to display the full legend label as a tooltip when hovering over the legend symbol in Vega-Lite. The reason is that the legend labels are being truncated, so I want to show the full label name on hover as a workaround.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I attempted to add a title attribute to the target HTML element using the following code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vega Legend Tooltip Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    const vegaLiteSpec = {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"category": "Long Category Name 1", "value": 10},
          {"category": "Long Category Name 2", "value": 15},
          {"category": "Long Category Name 3", "value": 20}
        ]
      },
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "field": "category",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"title": "Categories"}
        }
      }
    };

    vegaEmbed('#vis', vegaLiteSpec).then(result => {
      const view = result.view;

      // Wait for the Vega view to fully render
      view.runAsync().then(() => {
        // Select all legend symbol groups and add `title` attributes for tooltips
        const legendSymbols = document.querySelectorAll('.role-legend-symbol');
        
        // Array of category names for the legend symbols
        const categories = ["Long Category Name 1", "Long Category Name 2", "Long Category Name 3"];
        
        legendSymbols.forEach((symbol, index) => {
          // Set the full category name as the title tooltip
          symbol.setAttribute('title', categories[index]);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

The code successfully adds the title attribute to the desired HTML elements, but I’m still not seeing the tooltip when hovering over the legend symbols.
Could anyone suggest a way to achieve this in Vega-Lite or Vega? I’ve read about using signals in Vega for user interactions but am not sure how to apply them here. Vega-Lite is preferred, but since I’m using JavaScript to render the chart, I can also manipulate the underlying Vega if necessary.
Thanks in advance!

Like this?

{
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"category": "Long Category Name 1", "value": 10},
          {"category": "Long Category Name 2", "value": 15},
          {"category": "Long Category Name 3", "value": 20}
        ]
      },
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "field": "category",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"title": "Categories"}
        },
        "tooltip": {"field": "category", "type": "ordinal"}
      }
    }

UPDATE
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "height": 200,
  "style": "cell",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source_0",
      "values": [
        {"category": "Long Category Name 1", "value": 10},
        {"category": "Long Category Name 2", "value": 15},
        {"category": "Long Category Name 3", "value": 20}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "source_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["category"],
          "field": "value",
          "sort": {"field": [], "order": []},
          "as": ["value_start", "value_end"],
          "offset": "zero"
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "isValid(datum[\"value\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"value\"])"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "x_step", "value": 20},
    {
      "name": "width",
      "update": "bandspace(domain('x').length, 0.1, 0.05) * x_step"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "marks",
      "type": "rect",
      "style": ["bar"],
      "from": {"data": "data_0"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "category"},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"signal": "max(0.25, bandwidth('x'))"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "value_end"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "value_start"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "category", "sort": true},
      "range": {"step": {"signal": "x_step"}},
      "paddingInner": 0.1,
      "paddingOuter": 0.05
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "fields": ["value_start", "value_end"]},
      "range": [{"signal": "height"}, 0],
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "category", "sort": true},
      "range": "category"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "category",
      "labelAlign": "right",
      "labelAngle": 270,
      "labelBaseline": "middle",
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "value",
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
      "zindex": 0
    }
  ],
  "legends": [{"title": "Categories", "fill": "color", "symbolType": "square",
  
  
   "encode": {

      "labels": {
        "interactive": true,

        "hover": {
       "tooltip":{"signal": "datum.value"}
        }
      }
    }
  
  }]
}


Thanks for your prompt reply. This is the tooltip that will be shown on hovering over the bar mark type.
I want to show the full label name as tooltip on hovering over the legend symbol as the label names are getting truncated by default.

Does this have to be in VL or can you use Vega? Why not give the legend enough space so it is not truncated?

Vega lite is the preferred one. But vega would also be helpful and can utilize that as well.
Sometimes the legends label can be very long and thus can occupy more space than the main chart itself, that's why can't give a large labelLimit.

I've created an update for you in Vega that creates a tooltip when hovering the legend.

Thank you very much! Yes, this is exactly what I want to achieve. A similar approach should be possible with Vega-Lite as well, right?

Not to my knowledge. Don't forget to mark as solved and/or upvote if the solution helped. Thanks

Yeah this solution helped. I was able to manipulate vega as per your above suggested spec and achieved the desired behavior. Thanks!
